# knockoutjs get element.id via subscribe

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, target, subscribe

I have a select input created with a value of an observable.  I subscribe to the observable, but can't seem to get the ID of the select input.

```
<select data-bind="options: firstName, optionsText: 'name', value: $parents[0].selectCategory, attr: {'id': lastName}">
</select>

self.selectedCategory.subscribe(function(category) {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this.target());
}, this);
```

I can't for the life of me get the ID of the select element.  I can get the value of the options (which aren't set here), and the function that `selectedCategory` belongs too, but can't get the ID.  I'm pretty sure I could easily do this with just jquery.click, but I'm wondering if I can do it via .subscribe().

Any thoughts or comments?

Answer (score 1):

I am not pretty sure what you exactly mean by id. And your bindings are a bit messed up. If you mean the id of each selected input, then you can use `optionsValue` in your bindings:

```
<select data-bind="options: names, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedName, attr: {'id': lastName}">
</select>

self.names = [
        { name: 'Name 1', id: 1},
        { name: 'Name 2', id: 2},
        { name: 'Name 3', id: 3}
    ];
```

I left the `attr` definition you added even though it technically means nothing just so that you can elaborate more on why you may need it.

If you are interested in getting the `id` of each selected element upon change then you can do it this way:

```
    self.selectedName.subscribe(function(name) {
       console.log(name);           
    }, this);
```

Or of course you can get it upon a button click [in another function] this way:

```
    self.alertName = function(){
        alert(self.selectedName());    
    };
```

**[Full Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/N4LSa/)**.

I hope this helps and please let us know if this is what you initially meant.

Comment: Hi Diana,

Thank you for the answer.  I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, but I mean that I want to get the id of the select element.  As I said, I can get the value of the option that is selected, as you showed above.  The `attr` definition sets the id of `<select></select>`, which is what I want to get.  I do not want to get the value of the `<option></option>` that is chosen, but the `ID` attribute of the `<select></select>` element it is part of.

Comment: Why can't use `console.log(self.lastName);`?